# Why do I get a different RSA fingerprint when multihopping using ProxyCommand

Tags: security, ssh

I'm using the following config to connect to multihop to the target host (`gw2` and `target` have my public key stored in the `authorized_keys` file ; no `netcat` on all systems):

```
Host gw1
 HostName 255.255.255.1
 User john

Host gw2
 HostName 255.255.255.2
 User jack
 ProxyCommand ssh gw1 'exec 3<>/dev/tcp/255.255.255.2/22; cat <&3 & cat >&3;kill $!'

Host target
 HostName 255.255.255.3
 User jill
 ProxyCommand ssh 255.255.255.2 'exec 3<>/dev/tcp/255.255.255.3/22; cat <&3 & cat >&3;kill $!'
```

I cleaned my `known_hosts` file and connected to `gw2` using `ssh gw2` from the local machine. The fingerprint is different from the one I expect. The same happens when I ssh into `target` using `ssh target` from the local machine, the rsa fingerprint is different.

When I ssh into `gw1` and then into `gw2` (from `gw1`) `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` produces the fingerprint I expect.

I'm (fairly) certain that there is no MITM going on. Can anybody explain to me this behaviour? Should I be worried?

Comment: So if anyone stumbles upon the same problem. The eror was to only check for keys in `/etc/ssh/` whereas the active installation was in `/etc/ssh58/`